# Create an Access table by copying structure of existing table

Tags: ms-access

I'm new in SQL and Access and could not find any solution for my problem.I'm trying to insert the rows from 3 tables ( demand1, demand2 and demand3 ) into one ( demands ).

Every table represents the daily export for the demand. In each table I have the first column with unique parts numbers and the next columns are all the forecasts ( weeks ).

My goal is to have data for all week in order to see if and when the data changed.

I've tried UNION ALL with 2 tables ( see the code below ) and i have the following error :

> "Syntax Error in FROM clause."

I've searched on W3School and read what i could find in other websites.

```
INSERT INTO demands
SELECT *
FROM [demand1]
union all
Select *
From [demand2]
```

Thank you,

Comment: What's the structure of the 3 tables? Are the column names all the same?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not just using separate INSERT-SELECT statements for each sub-table and you are trying to do it with a single one?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax for Access:

```
SELECT t.* 
INTO [demands] 
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM [demand1] 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT * FROM [demand2]
) AS t
```

It will create a table `demands` and insert in it all the rows of the 2 tables.
You can find more here: [SELECT.INTO statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/select-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql)